# c extern undefined reference

Tags: c, extern, linkage

I'm sorry for what I'm sure is a simple mistake. But after a few hours I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I understand that `extern` needs to be declared outside a function and defined within a function. But I can't get it to work.

Here is my minimal code error.

```
extern double d;
int main(void) {
    d = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> /home/0KzRYK/ccCTD3Lf.o: In function `main':
> prog.c:(.text.startup+0x3): undefined reference to `d'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

Comment: You only have a declaration, no definition.

Comment: isn't d=0 a definition?

Comment: It's an assignment

Comment: @Akim Can you really talk about definitions for simple variables? I would just call it an assignment.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't understand. The following answer equates declaration with definition. According to it ```extern double d``` is declaration or definition. Which means d is defined in my case?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671925/what-exactly-are-c-definitions-declarations-and-assignments

Comment: `extern` is a promise to the compiler that the variable is defined somewhere else and will be supplied at linking.  The classic example is `errno`.

Comment: Bettter link is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46988095/1216776

Comment: thank you! here is another i just found that deals specifically with extern:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507423/why-is-creating-a-variable-using-extern-a-declaration-and-not-a-definition

Comment: This does answer the question (confirmed by OP in their answer). [Why is creating a variable using 'extern' a declaration and not a definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507423/why-is-creating-a-variable-using-extern-a-declaration-and-not-a-definition) I don't want the question deleted, but closed-as-duplicate is an appropriate state in my opinoin and all rep changes stay.

Comment: yes, that seems to be the answer!

Comment: I would say it's a non-apparent property of the language, at least for a beginner (cf. `static double` which is a definition as far as I understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the comments. My mistake was to assume that `extern double d` defines the variable in the same way as `double d`. But apparently it doesn't.

I would say this is a non-intuitive property of the language, at least for a beginner (eg. `extern double` isn't a definition but `static double` is).

Following your comments I found a related question that talks exactly about this: [Why is creating a variable using 'extern' a declaration and not a definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507423/why-is-creating-a-variable-using-extern-a-declaration-and-not-a-definition)

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is wrong. Variables with `extern` need not be defined within a function. But it must be defined somewhere (maybe another source file).

Example:

`main.c`:

```
extern double d;
int main(void) {
    d = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

`d.c`:

```
double d;
```

compilation:

```
gcc -o main main.c d.c
```

Comment: thanks, but can they still be defined within a function? that's what i am doing at the moment.

Comment: @Akim No. You can define variables named `d` in functions, but it will be different from `extern double d;` and just share names.

Comment: @Akim Only local variables can be defined within functions.